# Accessing modules in subdirectory when building pip package

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

This is my project structure currently;

```
repository/
|---- setup.py
|---- package_name/
      |---- __init__.py
      |---- module_a.py
      |---- subdir/
            |---- __init__.py
            |---- module_b.py
```

I install this with `pip install .` and leave the repository folder. Now when I try to import this package I can access `module_a` as shown below;

```
from package_name.module_a import ma
```

However on running the code below I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name.subdir'`;

```
from package_name.subdir.module_b import mb
```

Can someone explain how I can expose the modules in the subdirectory so that they may be imported from the package? I plan on uploading the package to PyPI.

If it helps, this is the repository - [link](https://github.com/IamAdiSri/hf-trim)

Comment: The `packages` in your `setup.py` is incorrect. `packages` should list all packages and sub-packages. That is why there is the `find_packages` helper function. Look it up... https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery

Comment: @sinoroc thanks a lot! I just realized that I need to either add the subdirectory modules  manually or add the find_packages helper. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @sinoroc, the packages in my `setup.py` file were incorrect. The `packages` parameter ([here](https://github.com/IamAdiSri/hf-trim/blob/3e2392ed5dd42f4bc7d4f19f6b4904d28da29b3a/setup.py#L22C5-L22C29)) should have listed all packages and sub-packages, however a less tedious method is to use `find_packages` as shown below, which does this for you automatically.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...,
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...,
)
```

You can read more [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can solve it by adding an `__init__.py` file inside your subdirectory as well, so that it’s treated as a sub module.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that the subdirectory has a __init__.py file in it already. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Having `packages = ['package_name', 'package_name.subdir']` in your **setup.py** tells the Distutils to look for `package_name/__init__.py` and `package_name/subdir/__init__.py`

- [Writing the Setup Script with Distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: Is there a less tedious solution?